# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 1

Tags: java, macos

I've coded a GUI game in Java which runs fine on my Windows PC, but throws this error on 2 Macs that I've tried:

[image: Error Message]

I can confirm that this isn't an issue with the JDK/JRE as I've tried with  multiple.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame;
    JButton button1, button2, u;
    JPanel panel, p2;
    JButton butinz[];
    JDialog dialog, spyz, last;
    JLabel l1, l2, l3;
    int clic=-1;
    int bRem, rRem, a;
    Board b;
    String turn; 
    boolean redTurn, spyMaster;
    ArrayList <Integer>chowzin;
    public Main() {
        chowzin=new ArrayList<>();
        redTurn=true;
        JLabel spy=new JLabel("Are you the SpyMaster?");
        JButton yes=new JButton("Yes");
        JButton no=new JButton("No");
        spy.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 22));
        spy.setBounds(65, 20, 300, 64);
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        spyz=new JDialog(frame, "TROOTH PLEEZ", true);
        Container pane2=spyz.getContentPane();
        spyz.setLayout(null);
        pane2.setLayout(null);
        spyz.setSize(399, 199);
        spyz.getLayeredPane().getComponent(1).setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.BOLD,16)); 
        spyz.add(spy);
        spyz.setSize(399,199);
        spyz.setLocation(486,279);
        pane2.add(yes);
        pane2.add(no);
        yes.setBounds(99,92,79,31);
        no.setBounds(209, 92, 79, 31);
        yes.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        yes.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 21));
        no.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 21));
        yes.setFocusPainted(false);
        yes.addActionListener(this);
        no.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        no.setFocusPainted(false);
        no.addActionListener(this);
        spyz.setVisible(true);

        frame = new JFrame();
      //  frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame.setTitle("Erry's codeNames Board");
        frame.setSize(1369, 739);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        b=new Board();
        b.moreRed();
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7, 6));
        panel.setSize(1299, 699);
        butinz=new JButton[36];
        printScores();
        a=0;
        while(a<36){
            butinz[a] = new JButton(b.board[a].getWord());
            butinz[a].setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 23));
            butinz[a].setBackground(new Color(251, 254, 211));
            if(spyMaster){
                if(b.board[a].getCamp()=='r')
                    butinz[a].setForeground(Color.RED);
                else if(b.board[a].getCamp()=='b')
                    butinz[a].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                else if(b.board[a].getCamp()=='y')
                    butinz[a].setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
                else if(b.board[a].getCamp()=='a')
                    butinz[a].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                else 
                    butinz[a].setForeground(Color.GRAY);                    
            }
            butinz[a].setFocusPainted(false);
            butinz[a].addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(butinz[a]);
            a++;
        }
    //  butinz[12].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    //  butinz[12].setText("");
  //      button1.addActionListener(this);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String clict=e.getActionCommand();
        if(l1!=null)
            newScawz();
        if(clict.startsWith("End ")){
            redTurn=!redTurn;
            turnChaynjd();
        }
        else if(clict.equals("Fine, man"))
            last.setVisible(false);
        else if(clict.equals("Yes")){
            spyMaster=true;
            spyz.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(clict.equals("No"))
            spyz.setVisible(false);
        else if(clict.equals("Got it"))
            dialog.setVisible(false);
        else{
            clic=b.checWichCard(clict); 
            JButton temp=butinz[clic];
            if(b.board[clic].getCamp()=='r'){
                temp.setBackground(Color.RED);
                temp.setForeground(Color.RED);
                if(!chowzin.contains(clic)){
                    chowzin.add(clic);
                    rRem--;
                }
                newScawz();
                if(rRem==0)
                    loseGame(false);
                if(!redTurn)
                    chanjeTurn();
            }
            else if(b.board[clic].getCamp()=='b'){
                temp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                temp.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                if(!chowzin.contains(clic)){
                    chowzin.add(clic);
                    bRem--;
                }
                newScawz();
                if(bRem==0)
                    loseGame(true);
                if(redTurn)
                    chanjeTurn();
            }
            else if(b.board[clic].getCamp()=='y'){
                temp.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                temp.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                chanjeTurn();
            }
            else if(b.board[clic].getCamp()=='g'){
                temp.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                temp.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
                chanjeCard();
                chanjeTurn();
            }
            else{
                temp.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                temp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                loseGame(redTurn);
            }
        }
    }

    void printScores(){ 
        bRem=0;
        rRem=0;
        a=0;
        while(a<36){
            if(b.board[a]!=null){
                if(b.board[a].getCamp()=='b')
                    bRem++;
                else if(b.board[a].getCamp()=='r')
                    rRem++;
            }
            a++;
        }
        p2=new JPanel(); 
        p2.setLayout(null);
        l1=new JLabel(Integer.toString(bRem));
        l1.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 25));
        l1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        l2=new JLabel(" - ");
        l2.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 25));
        l2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        l3=new JLabel(Integer.toString(rRem));
        l3.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 25));
        l3.setForeground(Color.RED);
        p2.add(l1);
        p2.add(l2);
        p2.add(l3);
        l1.setBounds(61, 43, 39, 29);
        l2.setBounds(90, 43, 69, 29);
        l3.setBounds(130, 43, 39, 29);
        JLabel fill=new JLabel("");
    //  fill.setBounds(170, 46, 2999, 199);
        JLabel r=new JLabel("");
        //fill.setBounds(299, 46, 2999, 199);
        JLabel f=new JLabel("");
        JLabel p=new JLabel("");
        //r.setBounds(499, 46, 2999, 199);
        u=new JButton("End "+turn+" turn");
        u.setBorderPainted(false);
        u.setFocusPainted(false);
        u.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 21));
        u.setBackground(new Color(238, 238, 238));
        redTurn=!redTurn;
        turnChaynjd();
        panel.add(p2);
        panel.add(fill);
        panel.add(r);
        panel.add(f);
        panel.add(p);
        panel.add(u);
        u.addActionListener(this);
    }

    void newScawz(){
        l1.setText(Integer.toString(bRem));
        l3.setText(Integer.toString(rRem));
        turnChaynjd();
    }

    void chanjeCard(){
        JButton fine=new JButton("Fine, man");
        fine.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD , 19));
        turn=(redTurn)?"Red":"Blue";
        JLabel lab=new JLabel("A neutral card has been converted into a "+turn+" coloured card!!");
        lab.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 21));
        lab.setBounds(41, 20, 799, 64); 
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        last=new JDialog(frame, "BAD NYOOZ", true);
        Container pane3=last.getContentPane();
        last.setLayout(null);
        pane3.setLayout(null);
        last.getLayeredPane().getComponent(1).setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.BOLD,17)); 
        last.add(lab);
        last.setSize(881,179);
        last.setLocation(241,339);
        pane3.add(fine);
        fine.setBounds(349,92,159,31);
        fine.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        fine.setFocusPainted(false);
        fine.addActionListener(this);
        a=0;
        while(a<36){
            if(b.board[a].getCamp()=='y'&&(!butinz[a].getBackground().equals(Color.YELLOW))){
                if(redTurn){
                    b.board[a].setCamp('r');
                    if(spyMaster)
                        butinz[a].setForeground(Color.RED);
                    rRem++;
                }
                else{
                    b.board[a].setCamp('b');
                    if(spyMaster)
                        butinz[a].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                    bRem++;
                }
                break;
            }           
            a++;
        }   
        newScawz(); 
        last.setVisible(true); 
    }
    void chanjeTurn(){
        JButton ok=new JButton("Got it");
        ok.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD , 19));
        redTurn=!redTurn;
        turn=(redTurn)?"Red":"Blue";
        JLabel label=new JLabel("It is now "+turn+"'s turn");
        label.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 22));
        label.setBounds(65, 20, 300, 64);
    //  label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        dialog=new JDialog(frame, "TURN CHAYNJ", true);
        Container pane=dialog.getContentPane();
        dialog.setLayout(null);
        pane.setLayout(null);
        dialog.setSize(399, 199);
        dialog.getLayeredPane().getComponent(1).setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.BOLD,17)); 
        dialog.add(label);
        dialog.setSize(399,199);
        dialog.setLocation(486,279);
        pane.add(ok);
        ok.setBounds(131,92,129,31);
        ok.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        ok.setFocusPainted(false);
        ok.addActionListener(this);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        //UIManager.put("OptionPane.minimumSize",new Dimension(399, 199));
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label,"TURN CHAYNJ", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    void turnChaynjd(){
    //  turn=(redTurn)?"Red":"Blue";
        if(redTurn) 
            turn="Red";
        else
            turn="Blue";
        u.setText("End "+turn+" turn");
        if(redTurn)
            u.setForeground(Color.RED);
        else
            u.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    }

    void loseGame(boolean b){
        JDialog lose=new JDialog(frame, "GAME OVER", true);
        if(b)
            turn="Red";
        else
            turn="Blue";
        JLabel l=new JLabel("       "+turn+" Loses!!!");
        l.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 25));
        lose.add(l);
        l.setBounds(65, 20, 300, 64);
        lose.setSize(399,199);
        lose.setLocation(486,279);
        lose.getLayeredPane().getComponent(1).setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.BOLD,16)); 
        lose.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        lose.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main test = new Main();
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Would help answerers if you'd copy the error message into the question, instead of posting it as an image.

Comment: @ruohola It's the title of my question. But I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line that produces the error is this one:

```java
spyz.getLayeredPane().getComponent(1).setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.BOLD,16));
```

changing it to:

```java
spyz.getLayeredPane().getComponent(0).setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.BOLD,16));
```

solves the problem, yo should check the size of spyz.getLayeredPane().getComponents() before setting the font

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is perfect. Would you know why 'getComponent().length' returns 2 on Windows, but 1 on macOS? (The rest of the code and the JDK/JRE are identical)